# Is there a way to update PSD files in Fireworks?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Is there a way to update the PSD file that I'm using in Fireworks? I'm slicing and making some action in Fireworks, but I have to change and add elements and layer in my Photoshop document. Is there a way that Fireworks can update the PSD without restarting all my slicing and actions from the beginning?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. What you want to do is apply your slices to a new version of the psd?

Comment: hi,i want to make change to my pdf document and continu slicing it in firework without starting all over.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your slices and copy/paste into the new document.

Comment: tis what im doing, was just wondering if there was another and more effective way to do it ;)

Comment: ctrl+a ctrl+c ctrl+shift+v. Can't think of anything much easier ;)